# issue with spring transaction management?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring and hibernate. i am using spring for transaction management. i have below class.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class Sample implements SampleInterface{

@Override
public List<Some> getData(){

//gets data after that it updates something

setStatus(someId);

}

@Override
@Transactional
public void setStatus(Long someId){

//sets status

}

}
```

If i dont keep @Transactional for getData() then i get below exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode
```

if i keep @Transactional for getData() then it will save properly. what is an issue here? any how i have @Transactional for setStatus(). Still do i need to keep @Transactional for getData() as it is calling a public method which will set the status?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is a bit complex and is caused by calling `setStatus()` *inside* `getData()`. When you are calling `getData()` from outside, you are actually calling a Java proxy created for you by Spring framework. This proxy applies transaction behaviour (starts read-only transaction) and delegates to your actual service class. This works fine.

However, when you call `setStatus()`, you are bypassing the transactional proxy and calling your service directly. In other words the request to `setStatus()` is not intercepted, and `@Transactional` **is ignored**.

There is no easy way to deal with this problem and [ejb](/questions/tagged/ejb) has the same issue. You just have to be extra careful when calling public methods inside the same class.

## See also

- [*8.6.1 Understanding AOP proxies*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) - official documentation
- [*Spring pitfalls: proxying*](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2011/10/spring-pitfalls-proxying.html) - my blog

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if i keep @Transactional for getData() then my problem is solved. is it good practice?

Comment: @user1016403: it's not the best approach, but I don't find anything better. You *can* extract `setStatus()` but it won't solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you call getData (without @Transactional on the method) Spring will start a read only transaction as that is the default for your class and when getData calls setStatus Spring will use the existing rad only transaction instead of creating a new one. That's the reason you are getting the exception.

The default transaction propagation is PROPAGATION REQUIRED. Read more on the topic at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation

Comment: IMHO in this particular case the `@Transactional` annotation is ignored altogether. Even using `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation would yield same error.