# Calling a Spring Bean's Method with Different Transaction Attributes?

Tags: java, spring

What happens if a transactional method with certain transaction attributes call a method at the same bean with different transaction attributes?

Comment: what attributes of @Transactional are different, in your case?

Comment: can you explain scenario which you would like to achieve?

Comment: Related: [issue with spring transaction management?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950895)

Answer (score 1):

With standart transactional configutration in Spring nothin will happen. From documentation (look in [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) for full explanation of declarative transaction management):

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional.

If you need to change transactional behaviour (propagation, read only status and etc.) using a method call at the same bean you can change transaction mode to AspectJ and using compile time wieving ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11797230/1375049) how to do this). But I have never do this in real practice, just for test. Usually it is enough default transactional settings.

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional's readOnly attributes has below exception:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
void methodA(){}

@Transactional
void methodB(){}
```

If you call the method like this, and you use Hibernate or other ORM platform:

```
methodA();
methodB();
```

will throw read only connection exception.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want to say by this?

Comment: @Transactional(readOnly=true) will open a read only connection, and Spring is not allowing you to update tables via SQL, saying that the connection is read-only.

Comment: Yes, but if in methodA(..) you only read some data from DB and not modify it, then it will work ok.

Comment: And I can't see any realtion of your answer to the question that was asked.